Device misinterpreted as mouse using STM32 device
I've found a weird problem ...
I didn't know why using my device (magnetometer), when I pluged the device into my PC my mouse froze my whole PC, my friend said it is because the USB was interpreted as Mouse and not as Serial communication using COM. And he said it is because my device sends data so fast and interpreted the "M" in string as mouse I don't get it. The initialization takes 1s though
Can someone tell me why it is interpreted as Mouse and not as COM Serial communication ?
Why sending data so fast makes it happen ? Although it was 1s for me
Why it freezes the whole PC ?
Here is the code :
  int16_t x, y, z;
  float x_s,y_s,z_s;

  LIS3MDLTR_params LIS3MDLTR;
  LIS3MDLTR.POWER_MODE = 0; 
  LIS3MDLTR.OUTPUT_DATA_RATE = 1; 
  LIS3MDLTR.SCALE_CONFIGURATION = 0; // REG_2 Scale 4,8,12,16 Guass
  LIS3MDLTR.OPERATION_MODE = 1; //REG_3 Single/Continuous Mode
  LIS3MDLTR_Init(&LIS3MDLTR);

  //Terminal variables 
  char log_buf[1024];
  uint16_t log_len = 0;

while (1)
  {
          HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, loggs, 1);

          setSingleConversionMode(&LIS3MDLTR);
          while (!isMeasurementReady())
          {
              HAL_Delay(10);
          }
          readMagnetometerData(&x, &y, &z);
          convertMagnetometerData(&x, &y, &z, &x_s, &y_s, &z_s);


              log_len += snprintf(log_buf+log_len, sizeof(log_buf)-log_len,   "-------------------------------------------------------- \r\n");

              log_len += snprintf(log_buf+log_len, sizeof(log_buf)-log_len,   "LIS3MDLTR Status : \r\n");

              log_len += snprintf(log_buf+log_len, sizeof(log_buf)-log_len,   "Oś X : %.2f \r\n", x_s);

              log_len += snprintf(log_buf+log_len, sizeof(log_buf)-log_len,   "Oś Y : %.2f \r\n", y_s);

              log_len += snprintf(log_buf+log_len, sizeof(log_buf)-log_len,   "Oś Z : %.2f \r\n", z_s);

              log_len += snprintf(log_buf+log_len, sizeof(log_buf)-log_len,   "-------------------------------------------------------- \r\n");

              HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *)log_buf, log_len, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
              HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD1_GPIO_Port, LD1_Pin);
              log_len = 0;
              HAL_Delay(500);
    }    

And here is the library I made
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <LIS3MDLTR-Controll.h>
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"

extern I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

void LIS3MDLTR_Init (LIS3MDLTR_params *param)
{
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    uint8_t data_to_send = (param->POWER_MODE)<<5|(param->OUTPUT_DATA_RATE)<<2;
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, LIS3MDLTR_Address, LIS3MDLTR_REG_1, 1, &data_to_send, 1, 500);

    data_to_send = (param->SCALE_CONFIGURATION)<<5;
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, LIS3MDLTR_Address, LIS3MDLTR_REG_2, 1, &data_to_send, 1, 500);

    data_to_send = 1<<6;
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, LIS3MDLTR_Address, LIS3MDLTR_REG_5, 1, &data_to_send, 1, 500);
}

bool isMeasurementReady()
{
    uint8_t status;
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, LIS3MDLTR_Address, LIS3MDLTR_X_Y_Z_Status, 1, &status, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    return (status & 0x08) != 0;
}

void readMagnetometerData(int16_t* x, int16_t* y, int16_t* z)
{
    uint8_t data[6];
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, LIS3MDLTR_Address, LIS3MDLTR_X_Y_Z_Axis, 1, data, 6, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

    *x = ((int16_t)data[1] << 8 | (int16_t)data[0]);
    *y = ((int16_t)data[3] << 8 | (int16_t)data[2]);
    *z = ((int16_t)data[5] << 8 | (int16_t)data[4]);
}

void setSingleConversionMode(LIS3MDLTR_params *param)
{
    uint8_t config = (param->OPERATION_MODE);
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, LIS3MDLTR_Address, LIS3MDLTR_REG_3, 1, &config, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}

void convertMagnetometerData(int16_t* x, int16_t* y, int16_t* z, float* x_s, float* y_s, float* z_s) {
    // Konwersja surowych danych do wartości w Gaussach
    *x_s = (float)(*x) / SENSITIVITY;
    *y_s = (float)(*y) / SENSITIVITY;
    *z_s = (float)(*z) / SENSITIVITY;

    *x = 0;
    *y = 0;
    *z = 0;
}

The initialization takes like 1s so it should be enough but still it freezes the PC.
I don't get it why it works this way and how my friend knew it was because the device sends data to fast ! Although I would like to know, because he asked me how long the data sends I didn't know how to answer it he assumes 5us but in my case initialization takes 1s because of HAL_delay(1000) so I don't get it.
PS.
The device used to send data through USB is a converter UART->USB.

Your magnetometer code might not be important to this question. The way you are connecting your UART to USB and your operating system are, however.

Perhaps, I just posted the code just in case. Because I was told is because of my code.

Your question seems very unclear - it mentions USB, but the code you show talks about UARTs and I2C interfaces. Please [edit] your question to describe all the components in your system, and how they are connected together.

See this answer. And the whole topic

@Flexz Small update it wasn't freezing only mouse it was freezing the whole PC. It says that the USB is expecting an M or B letter to consider it as a Mouse Device. But in my library the initialization takes 1s (HAL_Delay(1000)) in the library as you can see. So I don't know why it still freezes the whole PC and then the Terminal doesn't work, I see that my devices is sending but the USB port is no longer COM port so I don't get info but the device works all the time. I wanted to create a device that works when plugged.

@pmacfarlane I've added it in PS note. That I've used UART->USB converter
